# C++ - program has stopped working

Tags: c++, console-application

The code that I posted below is supposed to work in recursion (the Sort() function) even up to 1kk times. The problem is: when the Sort() function gets into loop number 43385 the console stops working and alerts: "The program has stopped working". Is it a problem with memory? If yes, where is the bad part of the code? Greetings.

```c
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;  
string a, b;  
int n=0,i=0,counter=0;

int Sort(int i)  
{  
    int x=0,y=0,tmp0=0;  
    char tmp1;  

    for(x=i;x<n;x++) {
        if(a[x]==b[i]){
            tmp0=x;
            tmp1=a[x];
            break;
        }
        else
            continue;
    }
    for(y=tmp0;y>=i;y--)
        y==i ? a[i]=tmp1 : a[y]=a[y-1];

    counter+=tmp0-i;
    if(i==n-1)
        return counter;
    else
        Sort(i+1);  
}  
int main()  
{  
    cin >> n >> a >> b;  
    Sort(0);  
    return 0;  
}
```

Comment: just before Sort(i+1) [actually just before or just after, I cant check it)

Comment: A few remarks:  the else continue in the first for loop is not needed, the loop continues to next iteration anyway.  tmp0, tmp1 are not useful names.  better names for example would be index for tmp0 and value for tmp1 or something similar.  It is hard to understand the meaning of these params with these names.

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps a call stack overflow because of too deep recursion?

Comment: And you should try to use a debugger (like `gdb` under Linux) to find out what is happening. You'll better compile with `g++ -g -Wall`, assuming you have a GCC like compiler

Answer (score 1):

To add to iltal's comment, you may want to print out information on strings a, b: a.size(), a.length(), a.capacity(), a.max_size()

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what this code is trying to do.  Here's a revision, with some print statements added, along with a random string generator.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

using namespace std;  
string a, b;  
int n=0,i=0,counter=0;

int Sort(int i)  
{  
int x=0,y=0,tmp0=0;  
char tmp1;  

for(x=i;x<n;x++) {
    if(a[x]==b[i]){
        tmp0=x;
        tmp1=a[x];
    cout << "x = " << x << " set tmp0 to " << tmp0 << " and tmp1 to " << tmp1 << endl;
        break;
    }
    else
        continue;
}
for(y=tmp0;y>=i;y--)
    y==i ? a[i]=tmp1 : a[y]=a[y-1];

counter+=tmp0-i;
cout << "  endof sort: a is " << a << endl;
cout << "              b is " << b << endl;
if(i==n-1) {
    cout << "Returning counter " << counter << endl;
    return counter;
} else {
    cout << "Running sort(" << i << " + 1)" << endl;
    Sort(i+1); 
}
}  
string randomStrGen(int length) {
static string charset =       "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890";
string result;
result.resize(length);

for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
    result[i] = charset[rand() % charset.length()];

return result;
}
int main()  
{  
n = 50;
srand(time(NULL));
string a0, b0;
a0 = randomStrGen(n);
a = a0;
b0 = randomStrGen(n);
b = b0;
// cin >> n >> a >> b;  
cout << "Max string size is " << a.max_size() << endl;
cout << "Calling sort" << endl
     << " n is " << n << endl
 << " a is " << a << endl
 << " b is " << b << endl;
Sort(0);  
cout << "  endof program: a inital: " << a0 << endl;
cout << "                 a final:  " << a << endl;
cout << "                 b inital: " << b0 << endl;
cout << "                 b final:  " << b << endl;
return 0;  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

counter is of type int but it has a lot of values summed in it which may be in all larger than int.  maybe try int64?

Comment: I did, counter value just before a crash perfectly fits for long int, or even unsigned long int if needed, but still - it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You could hard code some test cases, like n = 20, a = "xyz...", b = "abc...", and add print statements to your sort function to track what is going on.  Also, it may be helpful to add some comments to clarify what the purpose of the different loops are.